# Weblogic 12.2 Not starting after unexpected restart of windows machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 12.2 version. It worked perfectly,  but just before my system got restarted due to some power failure. From that moment My weblogic got stuck after showing the initial logs.

I cleared the cache, data, log, tmp directories, but that won't resolves the issue. Then i started a separate instance of weblogic from another folder, but there also it is going to stuck.

Here follows the complete logs displayed while starting the weblogic

```
 
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms1260m -Xmx1536m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=784m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimi
t
.
CLASSPATH=D:\Applns\Java\JDK18~1.0_9\lib\tools.jar;D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;D:\Oracle\O
RACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3\lib\ant-contrib.jar;D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\modu
les\features\oracle.wls.common.nodemanager.jar;D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbynet.jar;D:\Oracle
\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derby.jar;
.
PATH=D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\USER_P~1\domains\APPLIC~1\bin;;D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64;D:\Oracle
\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\bin;D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.9.2\bin;D:\Applns\Java\JDK
18~1.0_9\jre\bin;D:\Applns\Java\JDK18~1.0_9\bin;D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8;C:\PROG
RA~3\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\ICLSCL~1\;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\ICLSCL~1\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C
:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WINDOW~1\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\INTEL(~2\DAL;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\INTEL(
~2\DAL;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\INTEL(~2\IPT;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\INTEL(~2\IPT;C:\PROGRA~1\TORTOI~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK
18~1.0_6\bin;D:\Applns\nodejs\;C:\PROGRA~3\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\ICLSCL~1\;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\ICLS
CL~1\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WINDOW~1\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel
\INTEL(~2\DAL;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\INTEL(~2\DAL;C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\INTEL(~2\IPT;C:\PROGRA~1\Intel\INTEL(~2\IPT;C:\PROG
RA~1\TORTOI~1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_6\bin;D:\Applns\nodejs\;D:\Applns\APACHE~1.9\bin;D:\Applns\Java\JDK17
~1.0_5\bin;C:\Users\ASH\AppData\Roaming\npm
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
Starting WLS with line:
D:\Applns\Java\JDK18~1.0_9\bin\java -server   -Xms1260m -Xmx1536m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=784m
 -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib
\weblogic.policy -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -DnodeName=AB58 -Dservice.properties=D:\Oracle\Oracle_H
ome\user_projects\domains\applicationdomain\wl-stage\config  -Deai.interface.config=D:\Workspace\QBR_WORKSPACE\COM
PLETE-CHECKOUT\4.0-dev\config\application\adapter\eai-adapter-config -Dxibase.configuration=xconfig.xml -Djava.sec
urity.auth.login.config=D:\Oracle\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\applicationdomain\wl-stage\config\jaas.config
-Dframework.log.enable=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9900 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=f
alse -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket
,server=y,suspend=n,address=8001 -Xverify:none  -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchC
lassLoader  -javaagent:D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=D:\Oracle\ORACLE
~1\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=D:\Oracle\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server     -DnodeName=DEMO_APP -Dservice.properties
=D:\Oracle\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\applicationdomain\wl-stage\config -Dxibase.configuration=xconfig.xml
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\Oracle\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\applicationdomain\wl-stage\config\ja
as.config -Dweblogic.DebugSecurityAtn=true  -Dehcache.disk.store.dir=D:\Orac
le\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\applicationdomain\wl-stage\cache  weblogic.Server
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8001
```

Answer (score 0):

Note I'm not too sure of Windows, but the only times I got this behaviour in other OS was when the virtual machine couldn't write in the system's tmp directory.

A way to test this possible cause is to add this variable in JAVA_OTIONS pointing to a directory you know the weblogic virtual machine will be able to write:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/tmpdir
```